# How do I match everything if it doesn't contain a certain pattern?

Tags: regex

I have strings in a format like this.  I want to match strings that don't have `abcd` at the start.

```
abcd.efgh.ijkl
pqrs.efgh.ijkl
xyz.efgh.ijkl
```

I have come up with this expression `(?<!abcd).efgh.ijkl` http://rubular.com/r/jyZMIJxoNz

It kinda does what I need.  It matches the `.efgh.ijkl` part of `pqrs.efgh.ijkl` and `xyz.efgh.ijkl` and ignores `abcd.efgh.ijkl`.  But I also want it to match the `pqrs` and `xyz` parts.

I tried making a conditional like this `(?(?<!abcd)|.*\.efgh.ijkl)` but it's not even being recognized as a regex.  What's wrong with the syntax? Does it not say "If it starts with abcd then `blank` else match everything up to `.efgh.ijkl`?

Comment: @juergend: Not really. `^` is the "start of line" anchor, so `^(abcd)` will match anything that DOES start with `abcd`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[^\s]*(?<!abcd).efgh.ijkl
```

http://rubular.com/r/h11pUhuYSD

Should work for your purposes.  It even matches if the target is in a longer string.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a lookahead for this, not a lookbehind.

```
^(?!abcd\.)[a-z]+(?:\.[a-z]+)+$
```

The main regex is `^[a-z]+(?:\.[a-z]+)+$`, which matches a string consisting of two or more clumps of letters separated by dots.  The lookahead right after the start anchor ensures that the first clump is not `abcd`.

Be aware that, if it's really Ruby you're doing this in, `^` and `$` are *line* anchors.  That means the regex would pluck the second line out of the string:

```
foo
pqrs.efgh.ijkl
bar
```

...which might not be what you want.  To make sure you only match whole strings in Ruby, you should use the string anchors, `\A` and `\z`:

```
\A(?!abcd\.)[a-z]+(?:\.[a-z]+)+\z
```

As for your attempt to use conditionals, Ruby doesn't seem to support them.  But it doesn't matter, that wouldn't have worked anyway.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

`(?m)^(?!abcd).+$`

**Explanation:**

```
<!--
(?m)^(?!abcd).+$

Options: ^ and $ match at line breaks

Match the remainder of the regex with the options: ^ and $ match at line breaks (m) «(?m)»
Assert position at the beginning of a line (at beginning of the string or after a line break character) «^»
Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below starting at this position (negative lookahead) «(?!abcd)»
   Match the characters “abcd” literally «abcd»
Match any single character that is not a line break character «.+»
   Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
Assert position at the end of a line (at the end of the string or before a line break character) «$»
-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
[^"(a.+b)|(b.+c)|(c.+d)|"].*
```

http://rubular.com/r/51OShSXwUz

Comment: Not quite. `[^"(a.+b)|(b.+c)|(c.+d)|"]` is equivalent to `[^a-d"()|.+]` - it's a negated [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) that matches any single character except `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `"`, `(`, `)`, `|`, `.` or `+`.

Answer (score 0):

Negative lookbehinds are fun and they're a good tool to use.

But if you want to just match *whole lines* that don't start with `abcd`, an easy way to do this is to match lines that **do** start with `abcd`, then take every line that *doesn't* match.

Example (python):

```
In [1]: lines = [
   ...: "abcd 1",
   ...: "abcd 2",
   ...: "pqrs 3",
   ...: "pqrs 4" ]

In [2]: import re

In [4]: for line in lines:
   ...:     if re.match(r"^abcd.+$", line):
   ...:         pass # do nothing
   ...:     else:
   ...:         print (line)
   ...: 

pqrs 3
pqrs 4
```

Additionally, if the `abcd` you're looking for is a literal string (i.e. literally `abcd`, and not some other regular expression) then a string operation will be faster and easier to understand:

```
In [5]: for line in lines:
   ...:     if not(line.startswith('abcd')):
   ...:         print(line)
   ...: 

pqrs 3
pqrs 4
```